# Disable USB Connected Digital Picture Frame

Tags: image, batch-file, usb, frame, digital

Is it possible to disable & enable a USB connected digital picture frame in a windows batch file? I am currently using the DEVCON Enabhle/disable command & that does make the unit not shown as a drive & shows USB disabled in the Device Manager but the actual frame still thinks its connected. It is not until the frame is turned off/on or the USB cable is removed that it act like its not connected.

Here is my current program.

```
devcon enable *DEV_24CD
devcon enable *DEV_24C2
devcon enable *DEV_24C4
copy C:\Pic_Frame\Br_Frame\*.* E:\ /y
copy C:\Pic_Frame\Blk_Frame\*.* I:\ /y
del C:\Pic_Frame\Br_Frame\*.* /q
del C:\Pic_Frame\Blk_Frame\*.* /q
devcon disable *DEV_24CD
devcon disable *DEV_24C2
devcon disable *DEV_24C4
```

I understand this maybe an issue with the frame, but hoped there was something on the PC I was missing.

Thanks in advance.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

If you need the USB device to know it's disconnected you should have it reenumerate on the bus, which would mimic unplugging and plugging in USB, or possibly the on/off toggle in your case.

Instead of `devcon disable` issue [`devcon remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to disable and remove the device from the system completely. Then use [`devcon rescan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get it to reenumerate again. Depending on what you are trying to do you might need to use a combination of these and your original `enable`/`disable` commands.